# How can I examine the subnetworks of a nearly fully connected graph?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, clustering, connected-components

I have an almost fully connected graph in python with roughly 3k nodes and 9M edges. Each node in this graph is represented by a point in R3 and each edge represents the distance between them with a weight given by a weight matrix.

My goal is to visualize subnetworks (areas where points close to each other also have a dense set of edge weights) where the subnetwork is colored by the given weight. However, this is extremely computationally expensive, as there are 9M edges. I'm looking for an algorithm that can either return the subnetworks, visualize these subnetworks, or something similar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64321080/781723

Comment: I don't understand the task.  What is meant by "colored by the given weight"?  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  Why can't you just extract the subnetwork, treat that as a new graph, and plot it with any graph visualization tool?

Comment: @D.W. How would I extract the subnetwork? The problem with most graph viz libraries is they don't allow for viz in euclidean space (nodes represent poitns in R^3). The inputs to the algorithm would be a set of weights and a set of vertices - you could think of this as a directed weighted graph, perhaps. How, would I then return a subnetwork of points that fall in a euclidean cluster and have high weights.

Comment: @D.W. why did you point to my stackoverflow post with the same question? They were the ones that told me to come here

Comment: Maybe you can give a simple exemple in 2D with a few points. And please give a concrete definition of subnetwork.

Comment: Say you have points (0,1), (1,2), we have the euclidean distance between them, which represents an edge and we have some weight matrix, for which the entry in that matrix represents the weight of that edge. I would like display this graph in euclidean space while coloring the edges by weight. A subnetwork in my case is a cluster of connections where the distance is small and the weight is relatively large. This cluster would be surrounded (in euclidean space) by weights that are small or close to zero.

Comment: A useful tag/keyword may be [tag:clustering].

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need to be talking about this as a "graph" data structure.. you have points in R3 and you want to partition them into clusters based on their distances (or their pairwise weight matrix). This is more a statistical clustering problem than a graph clustering problem.

Here are some python functions to accomplish these:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html